# How to use template literal types for a strongly-typed "get property path" function

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with template literal types trying to wrap my head around them, and I can't quite figure out what I'd hoped would be a simple exercise: a strongly-typed function where `get(obj, 'foo.bar.baz')` returns the type of `obj.foo.bar.baz`. (This is a stepping stone to somehow being able to strongly-type my work's homegrown validator+sanitizer library that uses dot-separated paths to indicate nested properties.

My first approach was:

```
type GetResult<Value, Path> = Path extends `${infer Pre}.${infer Post}` 
  ? (Value extends {Pre: infer InnerValue} ? GetResult<InnerValue, Post> : undefined) 
  : (Value extends {Path: infer Result} ? Result : undefined);

function get<V, P>(val: V, path: P): GetResult<V, P> {
  // @ts-ignore
  return;
}

const val = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      quux: 123
    }
  }
}

const quux = get(val, 'foo');
```

But that never matches, not even the simple example in the end. (The compiler thinks the type of `quux` is. `undefined`.)

I'm probably missing something very basic - even without trying to do the string voodoo it doesn't match:

```
type SimpleGetResult<Value, Key> = Value extends {Key: infer Result} ? Result: undefined;
function simpleGet<V, K extends keyof V>(val: V, key: K): SimpleGetResult<V, K> {
  // @ts-ignore
  return;
}
const foo = simpleGet(val, 'foo');
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `simpleGet` returns undefined in the example you have provided, this may be the issue

Comment: @BooklynDadCore Yes, I know. Why does it return that and not the type of `val.foo`?

Comment: in the example the function has no logic just a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the type `{Pre: any}` has a key with the literal string value `"Pre"`; it is not a string with a key of *type* `Pre`.  To represent that you'd need a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like `{[K in Pre]: any}` or the equivalent `Record<K, any>`.  If you fix that, I  imagine you'll make some progress.

---

Now, popping up to the question in the title, namely

> How to use template literal types for a strongly-typed “get property path” function,

my way of giving typings to a "deep index" function that uses dotted paths could look something like this:

```
type DeepIndex<T, K extends string> = T extends object ? (
  string extends K ? never :
  K extends keyof T ? T[K] :
  K extends `${infer F}.${infer R}` ? (F extends keyof T ?
    DeepIndex<T[F], R> : never
  ) : never
) : never

type ValidatePath<T, K> =
  K extends string ? DeepIndex<T, K> extends never ? never : K : never;

declare const get: <T, K extends string>(
  object: T,
  keyName: K & ValidatePath<T, K>
) => DeepIndex<T, K>;
```

And you can see that it works as desired, at least in the type system:

```
const val = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      quux: 123
    }
  }
}
    
const barQuuxNumber = get(val, 'foo'); // {bar: {quux: number}};
const num = get(val, 'foo.bar.quux'); // number
```

I'm sure there are edge cases.  For example, woe befall you if any of your properties actually have a `"."` in their name.  I'd expect something like `{"foo.bar": {"baz.quux": 123}}` to do very bad things here.  But at least it shows that the general approach, a recursive type function that splits strings at `"."` characters, can work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgJIDsAmEAeAeAKgGigGkpNgI0BnKC4AJwEtkBzAPigF4ocSMzKoA9gCMAVhADGwKAH4oACgCwAKCjU6jJjz6oqxWcggA3CLSgAuZauKlyOqAGsIIAQDMuMrgG1CAXXOWiLVsqAAMAEgBvRhcTKAAxAF8AOkjo2IAlBJCPOTig-kdnN25pANU4BBR0bBxPOJ8CdLYzKANjWgCASnNWoxNlbpa2-qVlUEgoADUAQwAbelRpsgAFJYALXAJCNnYA615gtQZmDwqkNExNojYbfmHTfT7TFuIhp4BuZWV0cVnp2mg4gEyBoUCYEGALSu+20VBox1YihUglEEkhXDwAUKADlpgBbCAvKAAMimcwWSwgq2AG3w1wGHDYZyqlzp20+oyUQJBUkMcw4UAiARcAgELSFyNUQn+4rKqigAEcAK5KjAtACMACYAMxyhIBfVKQ1fLnA0HS2gARRVGGxSrxQlinHBwDkfNmBAA5CKBJ7OhzuaDkPaBS63XMvT6khaksrVX73lAAPRJ1r2x0dJRAA)

Comment: oh god you're right

got fooled by syntax highlighting matching them up

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted same function tho id didn't pass my two tests, first it should've had paths on intellisense, and second it should be type safe (already answered). So this answer is an improvement over the previous answer.

To have the paths in intellisense, we may replace `P extends string` with `P extends Path<T>` and by that, it also needs a bit more refactoring.
[See the code on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFpK0BcFMDOMCwAoEoEAsD2BXAGwBMAuUARgDpQsBDANzlAEsA7eAg5hOVn0AGY4ATqAAOtGFgQAaUACZqAIyYwAnmKYJaAprVZFQwuDDzDWoerS6GxwnGNga4cgMzUA7iIDWaNAGMcPhhQAHklACtQAF5QAG9QWjIYYTwXUCUyBP8yeVAAXwK-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-VB8nAyDUG48jNO0xCzwLXdtRk0DiMIyiXJU7c4nRIyuN7KSJOo7F-AIPAiDgVFvHXHABFA4U1EOa5-1QIA)

```
function prop<T extends object, P extends Path<T>>(path: P & Valid<T, P>, source: T): Prop<T, P> 

type Valid<T, P> = P extends Path<T> ? (Prop<T, P> extends never ? never : P) : never

type Prop<T, P extends Path<T>> = P extends `${infer K extends Key<T>}.${string}`
  ? P extends `${K}.${infer S extends Path<T[K]>}`
     ? Prop<T[K], S>
     : never
  : T[P]

type Path<T> = (T extends object ? Nested<T> : '') extends infer D ? Extract<D, string> : never
type Nested<T extends object, P extends Key<T> = Key<T>> = {
  [K in P]: `${K}${Dotted<Path<T[K]>>}`
}[P]
type Dotted<T extends string> = T extends '' ? '' : `.${T}`

type Key<T> = Exclude<keyof T, symbol>
```

P.S. Thanks to @jcalz, for helping me to find the solution to my question.